# Import Statements Inside Functions in Python

Tags: python, django, configuration

I have been trying to solve (in my own way) the problem of making configurations sane and 12-factor compliant for a Django app I am working on.

The following was my idea. As you can see, I wanted to fully isolate the specification of environment to, well, environment. Prior to this, I had to re-specify the entry-level settings file inside the `manage.py` for each new environment, despite already having separate settings files for each environment.

**settings.py** (to which **manage.py** would point)

```
import environ

env = environ.Env()
environ.Env.read_env()
DJANGO_ENV = env('DJANGO_ENV')

def production():
    import production

def development():
    from .development import *

def testing():
    import testing

def staging():
    import staging

options = {'production': production,
           'development': development,
           'testing': testing,
           'staging': staging}

print(options[DJANGO_ENV]())
```

However, I got complaints (errors) from Python 3.7 that import statements are only allowed at the module level.

My question is two-fold: how sane is this approach overall and is there a way to do imports at the function level?

Comment: Python does not give any such errors. Imports are fine at function level. Please show what you actually get.

Comment: It’s the `import *` that doesn’t work in a function (it needs to know the names for code-generation reasons).  But why are you doing nothing but importing in a function?  Something must be missing.

Comment: @DavisHerring, As I mentioned in the post, the file that you see is the entry-point from `manage.py` when it comes to `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`. In this file, I was intending to include settings, depending on the environment. The type of the latter I would fetch from a `.env` file. I make it work, but there are currently two `.env` files. It is not critical, but my intention was to combine them into one.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: So the `import *` is just to import submodules for side effects?

Comment: @DavisHerring, I am not sure what you mean by submodules. I was bringing everything into the current namespace. There are variables being set in that file.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Submodules would be files in the `development` package that would be imported (run) by the `*`.  Anything you “brought” would just be local variables in the `development` *function* (frame) that would evaporate immediately.